# Increment/Decrement operators on functions with return type int

Tags: c, function, integer, return

The following code doesn't run. Can I say increment/decrement operators won't work on functions with return type int?

```
int main()
{
    char x[] = {"test"};
    int size = strlen(x);            //works :)
    int size2 = --strlen(x);         //doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
error: lvalue required as decrement operand
    9 |         int size2 = --strlen(x);         //doesn't work
      |                     ^~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix decrement operator `--` decrements the object which is the subject of the operator.  The return value of a function is just that, a value and not an object.  It's the same as if you tried to do `--4`.

If you want to assign 1 less than the length of `x` to `size2`, you would do it like this:

```
int size2 = strlen(x) - 1;
```

Comment: I think the emphasis in the answer should be on the fact, that inc/dec operators take the value, manipulate it **and store it back to the source** as the OP appears to confuse those operators with a simple add/substract operation where this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says you need an object (lvalue) to apply the operator.

You could write for example

```
int size2 = strlen(x); 
--size2;
```